# paging in Java for a lookup

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to implement paging in an already running application, it works like mongodb where you get a query with bunch of parameters like

searchConditions ,limit( how many docs you want), skip ( skip these many docs)
and so on

and the response is back in json my task is to generate the previous and next link to the query that means previous page and the next page as per query

I came up with a method below

```
  public Paging generateLink(RequestFilter filter) {
    int prev_skip;
    int prev_limit;
    String pagePrev = "";
    String pageNext = "";
    int next_skip;
    int next_limit;
    String searchCondition = JsonUtils.toSimpleJsonString(filter.getSearch());
    String url = "http://isgswmdi1n1.nam.nsroot.net:7014/account-search/rest/api/v1/pmm";
            //properties.getProperty("paging.link");
    System.out.println(url);
    Paging pagingOption = new Paging();
    Result result = new Result();
    int count = luceneSearchService.searchCount(filter);
    try {
        if (count > 1) {

            if (filter.getSkip() > 0) {
                prev_skip = Math.max((filter.getSkip() - 1), 0);
                prev_limit = filter.getLimit();

                pagePrev = url + "?search=" + searchCondition + "&skip=" + prev_skip + "$limit=" + prev_limit;
            } else{
                result.setPaging(null);
                return null;
            }
            if (count > (filter.getLimit() + filter.getSkip())) {
                next_skip = (filter.getSkip() + filter.getLimit());
                next_limit = filter.getLimit();
                pageNext = url + "?search=" + searchCondition + "&skip=" + next_skip + "$limit=" + next_limit;
            } else{
                result.setPaging(null);
                return null;
            }

            pagingOption.setPagePrev(pagePrev);
            pagingOption.setPageNext(pageNext);


            result.setPaging(pagingOption);

        }
        return pagingOption;

    } catch (NullPointerException n)

    {
        n.printStackTrace();
        return pagingOption;
    }
}
```

call to generateLink method

```
 return Result.ok(resultRow, generateLink(filter));
```

the ok response method in the Result class

```
public static Result ok(List<ResultRow> resultRows, Paging paging) {
        if (paging != null) {
            return new Result(resultRows, 200, "Completed", paging);
        } else
            return new Result(resultRows, 200, "Completed");
    }
```

Underlying paging class

```
public class Paging implements Serializable {

        public String getPagePrev() {
            return pagePrev;
        }

        public void setPagePrev(String pagePrev) {
            this.pagePrev = pagePrev;
        }

        @JsonProperty("pagePrev")
        private String pagePrev;

        public String getPageNext() {
            return pageNext;
        }

        public void setPageNext(String pageNext) {
            this.pageNext = pageNext;
        }

        @JsonProperty("pageNext")
        private String pageNext;
    }
```

but my test method is failing

```
@Test
public void search_allFilterParamsAreDefined_hp() throws Exception {
    // given
    Map<String, Serializable> searchConditions = singletonMap("shortName", "GO");
    List<String> returnFields = asList("shortname", "gfcid");
    String returnFieldsStr = returnFields.stream().collect(joining(","));
    RequestFilter filter = RequestFilter.create(searchConditions, returnFieldsStr, 5, 10, true);

    int resultSize = 20;
    List<ResultRow> searchResult = getSearchResult(resultSize);
    when(luceneSearchService.search(filter)).thenReturn(searchResult);
    when(luceneSearchService.searchCount(filter)).thenReturn(resultSize);

    // do
    Result result = searchCoordinator.search(filter);

    // verify
    assertEquals(searchResult, result.getRows());

    assertReturnFields(returnFields, result.getRows());

    assertNotNull(result.getPaging());

    Map<String, String> nextParams = getQueryParams(result.getPaging().getPageNext());
    assertParam(nextParams, "search", toSimpleJsonString(searchConditions));
    assertParam(nextParams, "skip", "15");
    assertParam(nextParams, "limit", "10");
}
```

Comment: can you provide the exception stack trace you got ?

Comment: Hi Lex I am running the tests

and this is what I got
Tests in error: 
  search_onlyOneResultPage_noPaging

(com.citi.ddi.esales.as.rest.facade.SearchCoordinatorTest)


there is no exception trace